# MSSQL Bulk Insert Unicode 16

Tags: sql-server, unicode, encoding, bulkinsert, codepages

I'm trying to insert an UTF-8 csv file into the MSSQL.
The file contains scandiniavian, russian and chinese characters which do not get properly represented by the insert. e.g. Brøndy is being represented as Br├©ndy. Furthermore, this string takes up a length of 7 spaces instead of 6.

### First Try

Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE [PSAP].[staging].[ADRC]
(
[MANDT] [NVARCHAR] (12) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL
, [CITY1] [NVARCHAR] (80) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL
)
```

XML Format File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
<FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"' />
<FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='";"' />
<FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='";"' />
<FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"' />
<FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\n' />
</RECORD>
<ROW>
<COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="CLIENT" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
<COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="ADRC" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
</ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Bulk Insert Statement

```
BULK INSERT [PSAP].[staging].[ADRC]
FROM 'E:\sourceData\ADRC.csv' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FORMATFILE = 'E:\sourceData\ADRC.csv.xml' )
```

Data Example

```
"CLIENT";"CITY1"
"600";"Brøndy"
"600";"武戏"
```

Comment: You need at least SQL Server 2016 or later in order to correctly import data in the UTF-8 encoding.